# how to automate function names from a column in r?

Tags: r

i want to automate function call with different function names which are in a column of df.

ex:

```
Hello<-function(){
print('Hello')
}

function_call<-function(k){

    dataFunc = data.frame("a" = textString,
                          "b" = k(df,"C1","0"),
                          "c" = k(df,"C1","1"),
                          "d" =k(df,"C1","2"),row.names = NULL)
    return(dataFunc)
    

}

**df$a[1]*** is 'Hello' string it giving me as quotes

function_call(df$a[1])
```

i want to pass this string as parameter and call the function. k value is name of function we are call it from inside function_call

Comment: You want your function to apply that function on certain columns of your data frame?

Comment: i have a column with string names, i created functions with these string names so while iterating through column it should call the function i created. but here i'm getting string in quotes and not able to call the function

Comment: `match.fun("Hello")()` or `get("Hello")()`

Comment: I think your question is resolved with @Aurèle's comment (specifically `k <- match.fun(k)` inside your function). If not, however, please provide a sample (at least the first row) of `df` by pasting the output of `dput(df[1,])` (or more, if more rows are relevant).

Answer (score 0):

Please check Aurèle comment it worked for me

```
match.fun("Hello")() or get("Hello")()
```